# How to get variable defined within a function to also be defined outside of the function

Tags: function, file, variables, import

I have a python document containing an "encode()" function which i defined
i have imported this document into another file where you can choose the input
once the word is scrambled (successfully), it cannot be saved and printed outside of the function?
how to fix?

The simple encoding program:

def encode(x):

```
alphabet = ["x","y","z","a","b","c","d","e","f","g"," ","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
x = [*x]

i = 0
b = 0
for i in range(len(x)):
    b = 0
    while x[i] != alphabet[b]:
        #print("test")
        b = b+1
    x[i] = alphabet[b-3]
x = ''.join(x)

global message
message = x
print(message) #to test whether it actually scrambled
return message
```

the other file:

from encoderFinal import encode

message = input("enter message")
encode(message)
print(message)

The final line prints the input, instead of the scrambled input